# 'designed for iphone' flutter app white screen

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, macos

I have a flutter app that the client would like to use on mac with the m1 feature of 'Designed for iPhone'. I looked around a bunch but can't seem to figure out if there is something that needs to be configured build time.

The issues is that after installing the app on mac the app starts but it just shows a white screen. It works perfectly fine on phone.

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.